# Can't boot windows after both windows and linux were working together (Get Repair Windows Option)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bios, windows-10

I had both OSs working together, then I did a chown on an external HDD and can not longer boot windows.

Drives:
SSD 223 GiB
sda1 fat32     142 MiB boot,esp    (UEFI Boot)
sda2 ext4       37 GiB             (/ Root Ubuntu 16.04)
sda3 ext4      189GiB              (/home Ubuntu 16.04)

HDD 2.73 GiB
sdb1 ntfs       600 MiB diag       (Win10 RECOVERY)
sdb2 fat32      300 MiB boot, esp  (Win10 /boot/efi)
sdb3 unknown    128 MiB msftres    (Win10)
sdb4 ntfs       513 GiB msftdata   (Win10 Acer - main user partition)
sdb5 ntfs        14 GiB diag       (Win10 Push Button Reset)
sdb6 linux-swap   4 GiB            (Linux Swap)
sdb7 ntfs       200 Gib msdfdata   (*- WinShare)
sdb8 ext4         2 TiB            (Linux Data Partition)

*- I created the WinShare partition from Windows Disk Manager.  In Windows, it only contains D:\Dropbox folder and files.  When I set it up, I set up Dropbox in both Windows and Ubu 16.04 to use the same folder.  This morning I could access dropbox from either windows or linux and boot back and forth using either the bios change from sda to sdb or by using grub installed on sda.

I plugged in a 1.5 TB USB drive (not listed above, formatted as ext3) to send my backup files to it. In order me to access it in Linux, I had to run "chown buck:buck 1.5TB" (the name of the drive.)  I then transferred 500 GB of data from 1.5TB to a folder in sdb8.  After that, I booted to a clonezilla USB and backed up sda (disk to file) onto 1.5TB/Backup.

Then I went to boot back into Windows and I get the Repair Windows option.

This morning everything worked.  I could boot from the UEFI from either sda or sdb through the bios or I could boot either one from grub on sda.

After moving all the data and performing the backup, I was no longer able to boot to windows by changing the bios or by using grub.

Every time I try to boot, I get a "Repair Windows" screen.

Comment: Great!  After taking all this time to post the question, I unplugged my external drives and booted right into windows (where I am writing this comment.)  I guess my problem is related to the external drives formatted as ext3.  I'll look more into this in the morning.

Comment: And, after that, maybe you could write an answer to your own question and mark it as solved. ;-). @Buck

Comment: Pardon the time it took to mark the question solved.  I didn't realize I had to actually write an answer and then accept it, and then, only after time had passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem appears to be a windows problem but only when I have a particular external hard drive attached.  It is a USB3 drive formatted with EXT3 that I used to transport files.

I reformatted the drive and all seems to work well now.